# How to update Windows 7 and Parallels Desktop 9 before updating to El Capitan

Tags: parallels-desktop

I'm using a Mac for about 3 years now and updating OS X has never been an issue because it's free, but since I installed Parallels Desktop v9 and Windows 7 I'm reading issues about their compatibility on OS X 10.11 El Capitan where they are both not supported.

So upon coming to this issue I would rather ask an expert to tell me how to do it right and which should I upgrade first without damaging any of my files? Please kindly assist me step-by-step on how to do it properly.

Comment: It should go without having to say however always keep regular and current backups before modifying the system, using Time Machine is a good example. **With the caveats** _unless a older app has an known conflict that can cause the OS X upgrade/update to fail or OS X not run properly once the upgrade/update is finished_ **and** _the newer app doesn't require the newer OS X_ **then it really doesn't matter which is done first**.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably keep your apps up to date before installing an OS that you know will be incompatible with their older versions.

1. Take a Time Machine backup of everything.
2. Update Parallels through [this link](http://www.parallels.com/upgradepd11/). You'll get it for $49.99 (as opposed to $79.99) because you're upgrading from a relatively recent version.
3. Open the new Parallels and play around with your files to make sure everything works.
4. Once you're satisfied that the new version of Parallels works, take a new Time Machine backup.
5. Install El Capitan.

Good luck!

Comment: Well it's not necessarily just that simple.  As an example the version of VMware Fusion that's officially compatible with OS X 10.11 will not install on my current version of OS X so it cannot be upgraded first before upgrading OS X.  Unless a older app has an known conflict that can cause the OS X upgrade/update to fail or OS X not run properly once the upgrade/update is finished then it really doesn't matter which is done first.  I have many older apps running on a newer OS X and have no intension to update all my apps, only some of them.

Comment: I just checked. Parallels 11 is supported on Yosemite 10.10.4. [Source](http://kb.parallels.com/en/123276)